# PHP PDF to zip on the fly with blob data

Tags: php, pdf, zip, blob

I want to use the script below to add pdf files stored as blob data to a ZIP.

I get two errors that I do not understand

> Warning: file_put_contents(ATPstatement201203.pdf)
>   [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied

and

> Notice: ZipArchive::addFile() [ziparchive.addfile]: Empty string as
>   filename

I do not know what I am doing wrong?

```
$TP_Month  =''.$_POST["tp_year"].''.$_POST["tp_month"].'';
$TP_format =$TP_Month;

echo $_POST["ids"];

$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open('file.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach( explode( ',', $_POST["ids"]) as $Client_ID)
{
  $sql_qry="select *
            from   ca_client_statement
            where  client_id='".$Client_ID."' and trading_period_month like '".$TP_Month."'";
  $sql_err_no=sql_select($sql_qry,$sql_res,$sql_row_count,$sql_err,$sql_uerr);

  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_res);
  $file_content = $row['pdf_statement'];
  $file_name = ''.$Client_ID.'statement'.$TP_format.'.pdf';
  $file=file_put_contents($file_name, $file_content);
  $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=filename.zip');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipfilename));
readfile($zipname);
```

Comment: Another question for you: Why are you trying to zip PDF files in the first place? It is highly unlikely that you will get any compression at all, since PDF files (in general) also use compression internally.

Comment: handle multi file downloads neatly. compression is not important here i agree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Permission denied" means the web server doesn't have the permissions to write to the location you're trying to save the file to. You'll have to change the permissions to the directory that you're trying to write to using `chmod` from the command line (if you're on linux).

As a proof of what is wrong, you can do `chmod 777 /path/to/your/save/location`, however it isn't a good idea to keep the permissions that wide open, and you should dial it back to `644` or so.

And you're getting the "Empty string as filename" because `file_get_contents()` is failing (with the above error), and when it fails, it returns boolean `false` (as per [the docs](http://php.net/file_put_contents)), which is (apparently) being interpreted as an empty string filename.

Comment: Okay thank you. am I not writing on the fly? Im not trying to save the file anywhere? sorry if thats a stupid question

Comment: No you're trying to save the file to the location that's in the `$file_name` variable.

Comment: thank you, this was the problem. however the pdfs created in the folder are all 0kb. there is something wrong with the contents. I know the file contents is correct because I use this to output a single pdf to the browser perfectly.

Comment: Check your return from the database, it looks like your grabbing the content correctly with `$file_content = $row['pdf_statement'];` and storing it correctly. So, do `var_dump($file_content);` to make sure you're getting something from the database.

Comment: Content is now correct. files are output correctly to the folder but not added to the zip. each file is 16kb but the zip is still 0kb?